# Big O notation - Strange result

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I tried to use the big O function in Mathematica, but I got a strange result. It should be different because the two terms should remain.

```
(b*(1 + t*b) - a*(1 + t*a) + O[t])/(t*(b - a)) - (
 1 + t*b + (t^2*b^2)/2 - (1 + t*a + (t^2*a^2)/2) + O[t]^2)/(
 t^2*(b - a))
```

[image]

How can I get the right result?

Comment: Please include copy-and-pasteable Mathematica code and not images.

Comment: I think the expression is correct. If you evaluate each term on its own, you get `1/t +O[t]^0` for the first and `1/t + O[t]^0` for the second, and so when you subtract, you get something on the order of a constant.

Comment: @march is right.  Consider also things like `O[t]^n/t^n` for different `n`.

Comment: It doesn't make a lot of sense to have terms like `t * b^2` and `O[t]` in the first term, or terms like `t^2 b^2/2` and `O[t]^2` in the second.  After all, `b^2 t^2 + O[t]^2` simplifies to `O[t]^2`.

Comment: Thank you very much you all for the clarification.